# Mount cifs for 2 users

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

I would like to mount a cifs drive for 2 user accounts on a Linux server.

I have no trouble mounting the cifs drive for me, or for `sudo`, but I need to mount it so that two users can access it:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=BLAH,password=BLAH,uid=1000,gid=1000 //192.168.168.200/home /mnt/officenas
```

This works fine for my  access, and:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=BLAH,password=BLAH //192.168.168.200/home /mnt/officenas
```

works fine for `sudo`.

How do I allow 2 separate users who don't have `sudo` access to have read/write access of the same mounted drive?

There are a lot of settings in the man pages which I frankly don't understand, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may find [`smbnetfs`](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Smbnetfs) interesting. Read [this (rather old) Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/q/24348).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `multiuser` mount option. Also enable the `pam_keyinit.so` and `pam_cifscreds.so` PAM modules. The latter will store the users' OS login passwords in the kernel, so that the cifs driver can use them to log in to the server.

If the usernames or passwords don't match between client & server, pam_cifscreds won't work, but users can manually log in using `cifscreds add` (which also requires pam_keyinit). Either way, `keyctl show` can be used to check the keyring contents.

Alternatively, just mount the same share in two different places with different UIDs.

Comment: After many hours investigating this, I have managed to get this to work by running:-

`keyctl session` then
`cifscreds add server` then
`sudo mount.cifs //server/share -o username=userx,password=pwdx,multiuser`

But the mount command will fail on the next reboot because the credentials were not persistent.  How can I make the credentials be persisted across reboots?

Comment: There are PAM modules for both steps (pam_keyinit and pam_cifscreds).

Comment: Thanks. I have now added these two modules to /etc/pam.d/common-auth and /etc/pam.d/common-session as described in the man pages, and this is now allowing access after a reboot.  But I have noticed both mechanisms (pam_cifscreds and cifscreds) do not work as I expected.  After mounting, it is as if the session is root rather than the user.  The user can access directories it shouldn't be able to, and new files are created as root.  Any ideas?

Comment: setuids option seemed to fix it for me, but I think my main problem was due to a very old samba version on my Tomato router.  Moving to a Debian server with an up to date samba version has resolved all my issues.

Comment: @DanielEllis can you describe the exact files changed and those changes?  Especially *pam* changes.