# Share file between two computers

Tags: networking, network-shares, file-transfer, shared-folders

At home I have two laptops, one is running on Windows 10 the other one is running on Ubuntu 16.04.
Both are connect to a wireless router for internet.

How can I share files between these machine?

At the same time I want to be sure that only PCs connected to this router can see what they shares and transfer files with them .

Comment: Installing `samba` allows Ubuntu to access Windows networking. Then enable sharing on any directories you want to access from the other machine. (Hastur's answer appeared on my machine after I typed this.)

Answer (score 7):

- ***Normal* sharing**

  With samba under Linux <sup>[[1](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html)],[[2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!)]</sup> you will be able to see the file shared by a Windows computer and to allow to windows users to see your files.

  With windows you can share one or more directories <sup>[[3](http://www.howtogeek.com/225075/what-is-the-windows-10-share-feature-and-how-do-i-use-it/)]</sup> as usual for the previous windows versions.

  You have to set the authorizations for the allowed users, if only for reading or even for writing...
- ***Less normal* sharing**

  You can share from windows and mount it as a directory under your Linux filesystem with *cifs* eventually with more than one user settings, as  asked few moments ago in this recent question "[Mount cifs for 2 users](https://superuser.com/q/1097970/257269)".
- **NAS**,<sup>[[5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage)]</sup> a drive to be connected to your router or to minicomputer connected to your network<sup>[[6](http://www.howtogeek.com/208030/how-to-set-up-a-nas-network-attached-storage-drive/)]</sup>.

  > Network-attached storage (NAS) is a file-level computer data storage server  ... NAS is specialized for serving files either by its hardware, software, or configuration.
- **Cloud solutions**
  Another way, more complicated even if more interesting, can be to create your own *home cloud network* <sup>[[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OwnCloud)]</sup> as your private *dropbox* system.
  Or you can rely on external solution as *dropbox* itself (or the many others, google drive, yandex drive...)

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be get drop box. You can just drag and drop files onto your dropbox account and use them off of both computers. Dropbox actually has a lan sync option which can automatically sync over files to each computer.

www.dropbox.com

If all else fails, you can always use USB thumb drives! Which actually could be faster depending on usb 3 compatibility and the size of the file you want to transfer.

Comment: Hastur posted a far better solution than dropbox. Mine was more of a workaround option.